# Running commands inside docker container created using Dockerfile in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a Jenkins pipeline file and created a Jenkinsfile. Inside Jenkinsfile I have used Dockerfile agent and then running some steps. The steps are supposed to run inside docker but they are running on the host. 
Hers the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library(['abc-jenkins','xyz-jenkins-library']) _
pipeline {
agent {
    dockerfile{
        dir 'TEST'
        filename 'dockerfile'
        label 'docker'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Build Stage') {
        steps {
            echo 'testing stage running'
            sh "ls"
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstand it according to the output of `ls`.

For Jenkins pipeline docker DSL, it will mount the jenkins job workspace to docker container and change the docker `WORKDIR` to the jenkins job workspace.

Therefor when you execute `ls` inside container, it will print the files & fodler under your jenkins job workspace.

You can try other cmd or `ls` other folder that not exists in host to approve it's really be executed inside container rather than host.

Comment: This is almost certainly the source of the misunderstanding about what is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

You may using -> docker.image('image').inside{..}

```
stage('BuildInside') {
         docker.image('ubuntu1804').withRun('-d=true -p 8888:8080') {c ->
            docker.image('ubuntu1804').inside{
               /*  Do something here inside container  */
               sh "ls"
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to run commands inside docker container created by docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the agent creation stage inside the stages brackets:

```
stages {
    stage('Build Stage') {
        agent {
           dockerfile{
           dir 'TEST'
           filename 'dockerfile'
           label 'docker'
        }
        steps {
           echo 'testing stage running'
           sh "ls"
       }
}
```